# Can anyone help me regarding spring error?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

```
    **index.jsp**
    <html>
    <body>
        <form action="add">
            <input type="text" name="t1"><br>
            <input type="text" name="t2"><br>
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>

**web.xml**
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
  
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>

**Display.jsp**
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    hi there
</body>
</html>

**dispatcher-servlet.xml**
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
     xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
     xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
     xsi:schemaLocation=" 
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd 
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd 
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd"> 
     
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.juzar.controllers"></context:component-scan>
</beans>

**AddController.java**
package com.juzar.controllers;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class AddController {
    @RequestMapping("/add")
    public String add() {
        System.out.println("hi there");
        return "Display.jsp";
    }
}
```

Problem:
I am not able to understand why is this error in the image link is coming. I tried a lot but not able to find the root cause of it. It seems to me that there is something wrong in my project structure is that so ?

```
**Console output:**
Jun 09, 2021 4:18:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version name:   Apache Tomcat/9.0.43
Jun 09, 2021 4:18:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Jan 28 2021 20:25:45 UTC
Jun 09, 2021 4:18:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version number: 9.0.43.0
Jun 09, 2021 4:18:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Windows 10
Jun 09, 2021 4:18:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            10.0
Jun 09, 2021 4:18:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          amd64
Jun 09, 2021 4:18:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             C:\Users\Juzar\.p2\pool\plugins\org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_14.0.2.v20200815-0932\jre
Jun 09, 2021 4:18:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           14.0.2+12-46
Jun 09, 2021 4:18:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
Jun 09, 2021 4:18:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         D:\Workspace\Spring\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
Jun 09, 2021 4:18:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         D:\apache-tomcat-9.0.43
Jun 09, 2021 4:18:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=D:\Workspace\Spring\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
Jun 09, 2021 4:18:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=D:\apache-tomcat-9.0.43
Jun 09, 2021 4:18:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=D:\Workspace\Spring\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps
Jun 09, 2021 4:18:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
Jun 09, 2021 4:18:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -XX:+ShowCodeDetailsInExceptionMessages
Jun 09, 2021 4:18:28 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The Apache Tomcat Native library which allows using OpenSSL was not found on the java.library.path: [C:\Users\Juzar\.p2\pool\plugins\org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_14.0.2.v20200815-0932\jre\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:/Users/Juzar/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_15.0.2.v20210201-0955/jre/bin/server;C:/Users/Juzar/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_15.0.2.v20210201-0955/jre/bin;C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Users\Juzar\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\Scripts;C:\Users\Juzar\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\bin;C:\Users\Juzar\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\MinGW\bin;C:\Users\Juzar\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\Scripts;C:\Users\Juzar\AppData\Local\atom\bin;;C:\WINDOWS\System32;;.]
Jun 09, 2021 4:18:28 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8084"]
Jun 09, 2021 4:18:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Server initialization in [1411] milliseconds
Jun 09, 2021 4:18:28 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service [Catalina]
Jun 09, 2021 4:18:28 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.43]
Jun 09, 2021 4:18:31 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Jun 09, 2021 4:18:31 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
Jun 09, 2021 4:18:31 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcher'
Jun 09, 2021 4:18:31 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean
INFO: Initializing Servlet 'dispatcher'
Jun 09, 2021 4:18:32 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean
INFO: Completed initialization in 1240 ms
Jun 09, 2021 4:18:32 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8084"]
Jun 09, 2021 4:18:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in [3806] milliseconds
Jun 09, 2021 4:18:34 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping for GET /DemoMVC/add
Jun 09, 2021 4:18:59 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping for GET /DemoMVC/add
```

[index.jsp page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bx6BE.png)
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYBMX.png)
[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KRu2d.png)

I would be so happy if someone can find me the root cause. I am now just frustrated and without network help I wont be able to move further. Please help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need enable Annotation-Driven injection in the container. In your case, declare at `dispatcher-servlet.xml` (I assumed you don't use JavaConfig).

```
<context:annotation-config/>
```

By the way, how about consider to use `InternalResourceViewResolver` and place jsp file under `WEB-INF` folder.
Because keeping jsp file under `webapp` folder (directly) will result like user can access jsp directly.

For example, user can access `hi there` without passing `t1` and `t2` by typing `http://localhost:8080/DemoMVC/Display.jsp` url from browser. We don't want that, right?

`InternalResourceViewResolver` configuration example:

```
<!-- Spring MVC view resolver -->
<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property
        name="prefix"
        value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
    <property
        name="suffix"
        value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

Above configuration will be served as `/WEB-INF/view/Display.jsp` with following code -

```
@RequestMapping("/add")
public String add() {
   System.out.println("hi there");
   return "Display";
}
```